# Specify Factory db column names with FactoryBoy in a Django Test?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django, factory-boy

I've got a number of unmanaged models that I'm trying to develop some factories for so I can get some tests put together. The issue is that on a couple of them, they have `db_column` names and that is throwing an error for me in the factory.

My models look like this:

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="identityID", primary_key=True)
    person_id = models.IntegerField(db_column="personID")
    birth_date = models.DateField(db_column="birthdate")
    gender = models.CharField(db_column="gender", max_length=1)

    class Meta(object):
        # This is 'True' when testing so it's treated like a normal model
        managed = getattr(settings, "UNDER_TEST", False)
        db_table = "identity"

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="personID", primary_key=True)
    identity = models.ForeignKey(
        Identity, db_column="currentIdentityID", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    ticket_number = models.IntegerField(db_column="ticketNumber")

    class Meta(object):
        # This is 'True' when testing so it's treated like a normal model
        managed = getattr(settings, "UNDER_TEST", False)
        db_table = "person"

class YearTerm(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    class Meta:
        # This is 'True' when testing so it's treated like a normal model
        managed = getattr(settings, "UNDER_TEST", False)
        db_table = "[ALTS].[yearterm]"
```

My factories look like this:

```
class IdentityFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Identity

    @classmethod
    def _setup_next_sequence(cls):
        try:
            return Identity.objects.latest("id").id + 1
        except Identity.DoesNotExist:
            return 1

    id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    person_id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    birth_date = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyDateTime(timezone.now())
    gender = factory.Faker("random_element", elements=[x[0] for x in GENDERS])


class PersonFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    @classmethod
    def _setup_next_sequence(cls):
        try:
            return Person.objects.latest("id").id + 1
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            return 1

    id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    identity = factory.RelatedFactory(
        IdentityFactory,
        person_id=factory.SelfAttribute("..id"),
    )
    ticket_number = factory.Faker("random_int", min=1000, max=40000)

class YearTermFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = YearTerm
        django_get_or_create = ("name",)

    active = Iterator([True, False])
    name = FuzzyChoice(["Occasionally", "Sometimes", "Always"])
    created_by = SubFactory(PersonFactory)
```

My test case is *extremely* simple:

```
class TestCaseYearTerm(TestCase):
    def test_create(self):
        """
        Test the creation of a YearTerm model using a factory
        """
        year_term = YearTermFactory.create()
        self.assertEqual(YearTerm.objects.count(), 1)
```

But I get the following error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: person.currentIdentityID

I feel like this is because I specify the `db_column` name in the model, but I'm not sure how to fix that in FactoryBoy or to get factory boy to add a specific name to the factories attributes when creating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models can be improved. OP has `Person` and `Identity` models and wants that one `Person` corresponds to only one `Identity` (like a User / Person Profile). OP can achieve that with a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). So, one can edit OP's Identity model to

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note that I'm not using `person_id`. [Using _id in Django Model Fields for OneToOneField and Foreign is an anti-pattern](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/foreign-key-with-id-suffix.html). Also, in OP's `Person` model, delete the identity field since it's not needed anymore. OP will need to run `makemigrations` after this.

Then, OP's factories will get simpler

```
import factory
from factory import SubFactory
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

class IdentityFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    person = SubFactory(PersonFactory)
     
    class Meta:
        model = Identity
```

Don't forget to remove identity from `PersonFactory` as well.

---

If OP wants to keep things as they are, without many model changes, something I would advise against (but then again it depends on the goals/context), then OP can just add `database='special_db'` to the factories `Meta`, like OP mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623250/specify-factory-db-column-names-with-factoryboy-in-a-django-test/73624508?noredirect=1#comment130016946_73624508).

Comment: In this particular instance, it is not a OneToOne relationship. Turns out the original models were using a different database than expected. By adding `database='special_db'` to the factories `Meta` class appears to have resolved it.

Comment: @Hanny for a short term fix you may be right, but the way the models are need some redesign.

Comment: I agree with you. These are models that were created years ago by developers who are no longer with the company - they definitely need review. I agree. Thank you for your input by the way. Appreciated!